# Can't open file in Excel VBA, Run-time error '52'

Tags: vba, excel

So I've got this code

```
Dim fpath As String
fpath = "D:\stats.csv"
Open fpath For Append As #fw
```

However when I am trying to run it I am getting a run-time error '52': Bad file name or number.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, maybe it's a Office 2016/Windows 10 glitch that I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `fw` to be a **valid** file identifier number. To do so, get an identifier from the function `FreeFile`:

```
Dim fpath As String, fw As Long
fw = FreeFile                   ' <--------- get a valid file identifier
fpath = "D:\stats.csv"
Open fpath For Append As #fw
```